# Not able to map flat object for table joins

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Test.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id")
    private PermGr permGr;

    @Column
    private int status;
}
```

PermGr.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="permGr")
public class PermGr {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

`List<Test> testList = testRepository.findById(id);`

Now what it does here is it joins the `PermGr` without giving its primary Id at flat level

and what I want here , I want `List<Long> permGrIds = testList.stream().flatMap(Test::getPermGr)`

in flatmap not able to go beyond PermGr and not able to access id.

Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 1):

Every `Test` object in the `testList` collection has **ONLY ONE** `PermGr` object eagerly fetched in this case. Thus, I you only need `map` not `flatMap`. This could do the job:

```
List<Long> permGrIds = testList.stream().map(test->test.getPermGr().getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Disclaimer: I did not run this code snippet`.

Don't forget to `filter` null `PermGr` from the `testList` stream since the mapping `optional` property is `true` by default, making it possible for some mapping to be `null`.